# How to get an input[type="number"] to show all the values as selectable values?

Tags: input, woocommerce, types, numbers

I have an input[type="number"] within Woocommerce Bookings and right now this  shows a field where I can type a number but I'd like to show all the possible values (in this case 1 up to and including 8) and be able to select one of these values. How can this be best achieved?

input type="number" value="1" step="1" min="1" max="8" name="wc_bookings_field_persons" id="wc_bookings_field_persons"

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to do that

```
<input type = 'number' step = 1 min = 1 max = 8 onChange="limit_value(this)" onKeydown="limit_value(this)"  onKeyup="limit_value(this)" onKeypress="limit_value(this)"  >
<script type="text/javascript">
    function limit_value(_this){
        var value   = parseInt(_this.value) ;
        var min     = parseInt(_this.getAttribute('min')) ;
        var max     = parseInt(_this.getAttribute('max')) ;
        _this.value = (value < min) ? min : ( ( value > max ) ? max : value ) ;
    }
</script>
```